# MySQL query search includes results from wrong column

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I've got a search bar that is returning proper results, except that it is including results from a column I don't want to be searched.

MySQL query (file name `search2.php`):

```php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
  $submitted_search = $_POST['search'];
}

$safe_search = '%' . $submitted_search . '%'; //I know it's not 'safe' yet-bound below!

$sqlSearch = "
SELECT tbl.title
     , tbl.artists
     , tbl.date_starting
     , tbl.date_ending
     , tbl.opening_date
     , tbl.opening_time
     , tbl.category
     , tbl.cost
     , tbl.place_decode_strip
     , tbl.title_decode_strip
     , tbl.artists_decode_strip
     , place.site
     , place.addr
     , place.hours
     , place.web
     , place.admis
  FROM tbl
 JOIN place
    ON tbl.place = place.site
 WHERE CONCAT_WS(' || ', tbl.date_ending, tbl.opening_date, tbl.place_decode_strip, 
tbl.title_decode_strip, tbl.artists_decode_strip,
place.aka)
LIKE ?
 ORDER 
    BY date_ending DESC
";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlSearch);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $safe_search);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->get_result();

$searchResultsNum = mysqli_num_rows($data);

if ($searchResultsNum === 0) {
  echo "<h3>There are no results matching your search.</h3>";
} elseif ($searchResultsNum === 1) {
  echo "<h3>There is 1 result matching &ldquo;<i>" . $submitted_search . "</i>&#8239;&rdquo;.</h3>";
} else {
  echo "<h3>There are " . $searchResultsNum . " results matching &ldquo;<i>" . $submitted_search . "</i>&#8239;&rdquo;.</h3>";
}

if ($searchResultsNum > 0) {
  // data of each row
  while ($searchRow = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
    $date = strtotime($searchRow["opening_date"]);
    $sdate = strtotime($searchRow["date_starting"]);
    $edate = strtotime($searchRow["date_ending"]); ?>
    <section class="entry">
      <article class="site-info">
        <p class="site"><?php $web = $searchRow["web"];
                        echo "<a href='$web' target='_blank' rel='noreferrer'>" . $searchRow["site"]; ?></a>
        </p>
        <p class="site-add"><?php echo $searchRow["addr"]; ?></p>
        <p class="site-hrs"><?php echo $searchRow["hours"]; ?></p>
      </article>

      <article class="event-info">
        <p class="title"><?php echo $searchRow["title"]; ?></p>
        <p class="artists"><?php echo $searchRow["artists"]; ?></p>
        <?php if ($searchRow["date_starting"] != $searchRow["date_ending"]) {
        ?><p><?php
              echo date("F j", $sdate) . " – ";
              echo date("F j, Y", $edate); ?></p>
          <p><?php
            }
            echo $searchRow["category"] . ": ";
            echo date("F j", $date) . ", ";
            echo $searchRow["opening_time"]; ?></p>
          <?php if ($searchRow["cost"] !== null) { ?>
            <p><?php echo $searchRow["cost"]; ?></p>
          <?php } ?>
      </article>
    </section>
<?php }
}
?>
```

JavaScript:

```js
const searchButton = document.getElementById('search-btn');
searchButton.addEventListener("click", stopRedirect);

function submitSearch() {
  const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput').value;
  //  const searchResultId = document.getElementById('search-results');
  if (!searchInput) {
    document.getElementById('search-results').innerHTML = "Please enter search term."
  } else if (searchInput == ' ') {
    document.getElementById('search-results').innerHTML = "Please enter a valid search term."
  } else if (searchInput == '%') {
    document.getElementById('search-results').innerHTML = "Please enter a valid search term."
  } else {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('search', searchInput);

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "../phpScripts/search2.php", true);

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        const response_data = xhttp.response;
        document.getElementById('search-results').innerHTML = response_data; //this.response
      }
    }
  }

  xhttp.send(formData);
}

function stopRedirect(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

HTML search form:

```html
<aside class="search-field">
  <form class="search-form" id="search-form" action="/phpScripts/search2.php" method="POST" role="search">
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search all events" 
      id="searchInput" aria-label="Search through site content" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="search-btn" onclick="submitSearch()" />
  </form>
</aside>
```

When I search for `<` I get correct results from `event_tbl.title` (that is, it includes titles with HTML tags) but I don't want results from that column. I only want results from the decoded and stripped columns, `tbl.title_decode_strip` in this case.

Why is the query returning results from `tbl.title`? How can I limit the query to not include search (WHEN) results from `tbl.title`? I need to include `tbl.title` in the query because that is part of the HTML that gets returned in the AJAX. `tbl.title` isn't included in the `WHEN` part of the query, so I don't know why it is included in the results.

Comment: I don't think your `WHERE` clause is doing what you think it is. I think you're trying to create `WHERE tbl.date_ending like ? OR  tbl.opening_date like ?...`, but what you're actually creating is something like `WHERE '2021-01-01 || 2020-02-20' LIKE ?`. I'm guessing at the exact contents, but essentially you're creating a single string to compare, instead of a series of separate comparisons linked by OR. Since you haven't include the code that creates the search term, it's really guesswork as to what you'll get back.

Comment: @Tangentially Perpendicular Thx for the response. I've added to the query code (PHP) in the hopes of giving more useful info. I do want to search for `WHEN` the entered search term is in any one of several fields. I'm not sure I see the different between your two examples above, but I'll look into that. Any other hints/help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Don't munge the columns together. Just search each one separately.